# Experimenting with threads priority C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

i'm attempting to execute the code given as example here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle

But when i compile it in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 x64 machine
i have this error

E0415   no constructor exists for converting "std::thread::native_handle_type" to "ptw32_handle_t"

I simply copied the code.... where i'm wrong ?
Tnx, Fabio.

Comment: Include your code in the question as text, not a link to someone else's code.  See [ask].

Comment: What line is it generating that error on?

Comment: It would seem highly unlikely that Visual Studio's implementation of `std::thread` would be based on pthreads. That sample you cite says "on a POSIX system"; Windows is not a POSIX system.

Comment: Tnx Igor, i didn't notice that the author was referring a POSIX system.  So there is no way to set priority on std::thread in C++ ?